# How to debug css to get rid of scrollbars?

Tags: css, debugging, firefox, scrollbar

One of my sites http://ptp.bitplan.com uses (almost) the same css as

- http://diagrams.bitplan.com
- http://pi-q-robot.bitplan.com/

in all cases I run into the problem that vertical and horizontal scrollbars appear at positions where I do not want them to appear.

I am using firefox and try to debug the situation with the inspector.
[image: inspector image]

**What would be the steps to find out which element has the scrollbars I do not want?**

[image: right bottom]

see e.g.

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1312146
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1521712

why this is an issue.

Comment: see also https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/ProceedingsTitleParser/issues/23

Comment: why can't i right click "inspect" on the scrollbars or something equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Inspect each of the container tags "div" or just check all tags. Comment them out one at a time and see which eradicates the scrollbars. The problem is from your body tag... Set margin: 0 !important; in your css for the body tag

Comment: Thx for looking in to this. The margin setting has an effect but doesn't solve the debug problem.

Comment: Could you send a link to the project or paste the HTML and CSS codes here?

Comment: The three links are in the question just follow the github links on each of them. The websites are mostly up-to-date with the code and include the css e.g. https://github.com/BITPlan/diagrams/blob/master/web/css/diagrams.css which I changed this morning accordingt to your hint.

Comment: I made a pull request to your repo. Noticed you omitted a colon on line 16

Comment: thx i merged it. Interestingly the colon seemed to make no difference when i tested it so just leaving out the old margins was better than having them. ptp.bitplan.com and diagrams.bitplan.com are updated just refresh your browser cache when looking at them. It now looks better but the debug problem would be to get from the scrollbars to the relevant element by clicking in the inspector - we need a new example now :-(